# Laravel Monolog Syslog specify individual log file?

Tags: laravel, syslog, monolog

I have Laravel setup so Monolog logs to `syslog`. Here is whats' in my `start/global.php`:

```
$monolog = Log::getMonolog();
$monolog->pushHandler(new Monolog\Handler\SyslogHandler('mywebsitename'));
```

This works well, except all log messages are dumped into `/var/log/messages`.

How can I specify a specific log file instead of `messages`? I've seen something called custom "channels" with Monolog. Is it something to do with that?

Also, how do I make sure that this log file is rotated like the rest of my log files?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Laravel 4.2, and in my setLog function I've added the RotatingFileHandler. This will solve both problems for you.

This code creates a file called mttParser-{Y-m-d}.log in app/storage/logs/import/, where `{Y-m-d}` is converted to todays date. The second parameter to the RotatingFileHandler, 10, sets to keep 10 versions of the log file before deleting them.

The IntrospectionProcessor simply adds the method, class, line number, where the log was called.

```
trait LogTrait
{
    /**
     * @var string The location within the storage path to put the log files
     */
    protected $logFileLocation = 'logs/import/';

    protected $logFileName = 'mttParser.log';

    /**
     * @var Logger
     */
    protected $log;

    /**
     * Returns a valid log file, re-using an existing one if possible
     *
     * @return \Monolog\Logger
     */
    public function getLog()
    {
        // Set a log file
        if (!isset( $this->log )) {
            $this->setLog();
        }

        // If it's been set somewhere else, re-create it
        if ('Monolog\Logger' !== get_class( $this->log )) {
            $this->setLog();
        }

        return $this->log;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the log file
     */
    public function setLog()
    {
        $this->log = new Logger( 'mttParserLog' );
        // Make sure our directory exists
        if (!File::isDirectory( storage_path( $this->logFileLocation ) )) {
            File::makeDirectory( storage_path( $this->logFileLocation ) );
        }

        $this->log->pushHandler( new RotatingFileHandler( storage_path( $this->logFileLocation . $this->logFileName ),
            10 ) );
        $this->log->pushProcessor( new IntrospectionProcessor() );
    }
}
```